# Why the following react functional component does not work properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

It is quite straight forward, when you press "add" it should add(and it adds) and when you press "remove" it should pop the last element and re-render the list but it doesn't. I am make mistake somewhere?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const Test = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    const add = () => {
        setList([list.length, ...list]);
    }

    const remove = () => {
        list.pop();
        setList(list);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(list)
    }, [list])

    return (<ul>
        <button onClick={add}>add</button>
        <button onClick={remove}>remove</button>
        {list.map(el => <li>{el}</li>)}
    </ul>)
}

export default Test;
```

**UPDATE:**
Actually it updates the state by removing the last element but the re-render happen only when button "add" is pressed

Comment: your add function seems to be wrong you are pushing length of list and then adding whole list to it

Comment: Don't mutate things in your state, use e.g. `list.slice(0, -1)` to get an array of all but the last value.

Comment: @amardeepsaini thats because I want to construct the list with the newest elements in front:
Initialy the list is [] (len = 0), when add is pressed list is set to ` [0, ...[]] = [0](len = 1)` then on second add click list become `[1, ...[0]] = [1, 0](len 2)` and so on.

Comment: @HristoTodorov, worst part of your add function is that you are not doing anything in it, you are not adding any new list to it so it won't work.

Comment: @HristoTodorov regarding your remove function it will not work as you have to mutate the state first then perform operation and then set it eg

Comment: let updatedList = [...list] then pop from updatedList and then do setList(updatedList)

Comment: @amardeepsaini regarding the comment for the add function it adds the length of the array to the beginning of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended to modify the state itself because it is immutable.

So instead using [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) on the original state of the array, first I suggest to clone that one and remove the required element from there, then the result should passed to `setList()` function.

Try as the following instead:

```
const remove = () => {
    const copy = [...list];
    copy.pop();
    setList(copy);
}
```

Think about the following:

```js
const list = [1,3,5,6,7];
const copy = [...list];
copy.pop();

console.log(list);
console.log(copy);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you it works. So react change the state when the container is changed not only the value it contains?

Comment: @HristoTodorov It changes the state once you call the `setState` function which was in your case `setList`. It's not a good practice to modify directly the state.

Comment: Thank yoy! I got it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a new array in this case, `setList(list)` will not cause React to re-render because it's still the same array you're using.

Try `setList([...list])` in your `remove` function.

There's also an alternative to `pop`, and doesn't mutate the original variable:

```js
  const remove = () => {
    const [removed, ...newList] = list
    setList(newList)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you it works. So react change the state when the container is changed not only the value it contains?

Comment: See this from React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

Essentially, when you're doing `setList(list)`, you're telling react to update the state to the `list` reference which wasn't changed. By cloning the `list`, a new reference is created, only then React would be able to tell it's a different state.